# Execute code on multiple repositories inheriting a base Repository<TEntity> class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, polymorphism

To streamline my code, I'm wondering if there is a way to pass my repository classes as their inherited base `Repository<TEntity>`, which uses a generic, using polymorphism. I understand why my code doesn't work, but I'm wondering if I'm missing something and if passing multiple repository classes as `Repository<TEntity>` to use its methods is possible.

I manually typed this code here. Please let me know if I edited wrong.

Base Repository Class, uses Entity Framework context class...

```
public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    protected readonly DbContext Context;

    public Repository(DbContext context)
    {
        this.Context = context;
    }

    public IEnumerable<TEntity> MethodOne()
    {
        return Context.Set<TEntity>().DoSomething();
    }

    public IEnumerable<TEntity> MethodTwo()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Repository example ...

```
internal class SomeModelRepository : Repository<SomeModel>
{
    public __DbContext DbContext
    {
        get { return Context as __DbContext; }
    }

    public SomeModelRepository(__DbContext context) : base(context) { }
}
```

Unit Of Work class...

```
internal class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private readonly __DbContext _context;

    public SomeModelRepository SomeModels { get; private set; }
    public SomeOtherModelRepository SomeOtherModels { get; private set; }

    public UnitOfWorkProject(__DbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        SomeModels = new SomeModelRepository(context);
        SomeOtherModels = new SomeOtherModelRepository(context);
    }
    ...
}
```

Client class that wants to do the same action on a bunch of EF models. Polymorphism cannot work here because SomeModelRepository cannot be passed as `Repository<TEntity>` even though SomeModelRepository inherits `Repository<TEntity>`. This is not surprising, but is there a way to pass multiple repository types and call the same method in the `Repository<TEntity>` class?

```
public class Client
{
 UnitOfWork _UnitOfWork;

 public Client()
 {
      UnitOfWork _UnitOfWork = new(new __DbContext());
 }

 public void DoSomeClientStuff()
 {
      //Of course, this doesn't work
      ClientMethod(new List<Repository<object>> { _UnitOfWork.SomeModels, _UnitOfWork.SomeOtherModels }); 
      _UnitOfWork.SaveChanges();
 }

 private void ClientMethod(IEnumerable<Repository<object>> repositories)
 {
      foreach (Repository<object> repository in repositories)
      {
          repository.MethodOne();
          repository.MethodTwo();
      }
  }
```

}

Comment: Side note: since you understand that there is no "polymorphism" between unrelated specific instances of `Repository<TEntity>` types you may want to edit out that "polymorphism" word/tag from the question.

Comment: It feels I do not understand the problem but regardless of that I believe there is no reason your client class should be using the concrete types (Repository<T>) instead of the abstractions (IRepository<T>).

Comment: @Veverke We're following a specific pre-established architecture.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear if you have access to `IRepository<TEntity>` interface definition or if it is defined with EF ?
If you can update the interface, you could use covariance.

```
public interface IRepository<out TEntity>
{
    IEnumerable<TEntity> MethodOne();

    IEnumerable<TEntity> MethodTwo();
}
```

Then, in `Client` class use the covariant interface

```
public class Client
{
    UnitOfWork _UnitOfWork;

    public Client()
    {
        UnitOfWork _UnitOfWork = new(new __DbContext());
    }

    public void DoSomeClientStuff()
    {
        //Of course, this doesn't work
        ClientMethod(new List<IRepository<object>> { _UnitOfWork.SomeModels, _UnitOfWork.SomeOtherModels });
        _UnitOfWork.SaveChanges();
    }

    private void ClientMethod(IEnumerable<IRepository<object>> repositories)
    {
        foreach (IRepository<object> repository in repositories)
        {
            repository.MethodOne();
            repository.MethodTwo();
        }
    }
}
```